# Should conda, or conda-forge be used for Python environments?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

`Conda` and `conda-forge` are both Python package managers. What is the appropriate choice when a package exists in both repositories? Django, for example, can be installed with either, but the difference between the two is several dependencies (conda-forge has many more). There is no explanation for these differences, not even a simple README.

Which one should be used? Conda or conda-forge? Does it matter?

Comment: "Conda and conda-forge are both Python package managers."  I don't think that's true.  I don't think those are even in the same category of thing. `conda` is a package manager and `conda-forge` is a channel.  Maybe it was true when this question was asked?

Answer (score 363, accepted):

The short answer is that, in my experience generally, it doesn't matter which you use.

The long answer:

So `conda-forge` is an additional channel from which packages may be installed. In this sense, it is not any more special than the default channel, or any of the other hundreds (thousands?) of channels that people have posted packages to. You can add your own channel if you sign up at https://anaconda.org and upload your own Conda packages.

Here we need to make the distinction, which I think you're not clear about from your phrasing in the question, between `conda`, the cross-platform package manager, and `conda-forge`, the package channel. Anaconda Inc. (formerly Continuum IO), the main developers of the `conda` software, also maintain a separate channel of packages, which is the default when you type `conda install packagename` without changing any options.

There are three ways to change the options for channels. The first two are done every time you install a package and the last one is persistent. The first one is to specify a channel every time you install a package:

```
conda install -c some-channel packagename
```

Of course, the package has to exist on that channel. This way will install `packagename` and all its dependencies from `some-channel`. Alternately, you can specify:

```
conda install some-channel::packagename
```

The package still has to exist on `some-channel`, but now, only `packagename` will be pulled from `some-channel`. Any other packages that are needed to satisfy dependencies will be searched for from your default list of channels.

To see your channel configuration, you can write:

```
conda config --show channels
```

You can control the order that channels are searched with `conda config`. You can write:

```
conda config --add channels some-channel
```

to add the channel `some-channel` to the top of the `channels` configuration list. This gives `some-channel` the highest priority. Priority determines ([in part](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/channels.html)) which channel is selected when more than one channel has a particular package. To add the channel to the end of the list and give it the lowest priority, type

```
conda config --append channels some-channel
```

If you would like to remove the channel that you added, you can do so by writing

```
conda config --remove channels some-channel
```

See

```
conda config -h
```

for more options.

With all of that said, there are four main reasons to use the `conda-forge` channel instead of the `defaults` channel maintained by Anaconda:

1. Packages on `conda-forge` *may* be more up-to-date than those on the `defaults` channel
2. There are packages on the `conda-forge` channel that aren't available from `defaults`
3. You would prefer to use a dependency such as `openblas` (from `conda-forge`) instead of `mkl` (from `defaults`).
4. If you are installing a package that requires a compiled library (e.g., a C extension or a wrapper around a C library), it *may* reduce the chance of incompatibilities if you install all of the packages in an environment from a single channel due to binary compatibility of the base C library (but this advice may be out of date/change in the future). For reference, see [the Conda Forge post on mixing channels](https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/tipsandtricks.html#using-multiple-channels).

Comment: Thanks! I have two related questions:  
1. how can I find out which channel is good to try and;     
2. after I config on one channel, how can I reset it back to default?

Comment: @Kenny To answer your first question, you should search for the package you want on https://anaconda.org and see which channels have the package. I edited the answer to answer your second question. However, I'd also note that if you want to install a single package from a channel, it is probably easier to use the `conda install -c some-channel packagename` way of writing the command

Comment: this is great! Is there a comparison available between conda-forge and conda in terms of # of supported modules, freshness, coverage etc?

Comment: Isn't `mkl` faster than `openblas`?

Comment: @endolith Maybe, but 1) possibly only on Intel processors and 2) it is not open source

Comment: I'm currently working in with spatial GIS data and conda-forge has a lot, lot more packages (gdal, geopandas, fiona, shapely etc.) that are up to date with proper dependencies configured that aren't on the normal conda channel. The standard pip-install had multiple dependency issues. Based on this would definitely recommend conda-forge as the go-to channel.

Comment: Thanks for the info about `conda-forge` using different dependencies with `mkl` and `openblas`! I

Answer (score 51):

Anaconda has changed their [Terms of Service](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/sustaining-our-stewardship-of-the-open-source-data-science-community) so that "heavy commercial users" would have to pay, which doesn't include `conda-forge` channel.

The `main` channel is maintained by Anaconda, while `conda-forge` is maintained by the maintainers of the packages themselves. Each have their pros and cons. Packages on the `main` channel are usually compatible with one another, meaning you can install almost as many as you want, and you won't have dependency conflicts. On the other hand, packages on the `conda-forge` channel receive the updates much faster than the `main` channel since the maintainers themselves push the updates to the channel. From time to time, there are also patches done by Anaconda on packages available on the `main` channel which are not supported and done by the maintainers of the package, which can be good or bad, but definitely out of hands of the maintainers and not supported by them.

You probably would want to stick to `conda-forge` if you don't want to pay for the usage and you would be okay with the versions available on [`pypi`](https://pypi.org/). As stated in the [docs](https://conda-forge.org/#about):

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda config --set channel_priority strict
conda install <package-name>
```

You could also use [miniforge](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge/#download) which has `conda-forge` as the default channel, and supports ppc64le and aarch64 platforms as well as the other usual ones.

If you have `conda` installed and would like to remove the default channels, you can use

```
conda config --show channels
```

to see your channels, and can use

```
conda config --remove channels channel-name
```

to remove a channel.

Comment: Do you know for sure that using conda-forge as the default channel eliminates the terms of service violation? I have heard that because the base conda uses the default channel on installation it might still be a problem, thoughts?

Comment: That's a good point, and I'm not sure about it. If one wants to be safe, one can always fall back to `miniforge`.

Comment: @adrin is [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) free for commercial use also?

Comment: @YousefSaber I'm not sure about miniconda, but `conda` itself is BSD licensed and you can use it freely.

Comment: Can you also remove the conda channels?

Comment: The top answer above has also an answer for you @lalala

Comment: pwang99 (the current Anaconda CEO, I believe) on Reddit confirmed that miniconda is a free alternative to Anaconda: https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/lvr85n/i_want_to_use_python_commercially_for_free_is/gqiae2i?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Comment: @YousefSaber Miniconda still sources from the default Anaconda Cloud channels, which fall under the ToS. You would need to update the channels as per this post, then update the packages to re-source from non-default channels. Or just start from Miniforge or one of its variants.

Comment: @merv yeah I believe everything is clear now, Miniconda is free for commercial use, but using the default channel requires some license fees that's why I've changed the settings to use [Conda-forge](https://conda-forge.org/blog/posts/2020-11-20-anaconda-tos/) instead to avoid thos new TOS.

Comment: Are there drawbacks to mixing packages from the default channel and conda-forge? E.g. in terms of compatibility or something else?

Comment: @Joooeey you can always mix packages from different channels, that goes for the `main` and the `conda-forge` channels as well.

Answer (score 8):

The conda-forge channel is where you can find packages that have been built for conda but yet to be part of the official Anaconda distribution.

Generally, you can use any of them.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience the **channel** `conda-forge` provides more packages and they are also more up-to-date. That is why I use it as my default channel which can be done like so

```bash
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda config --set channel_priority strict
```

Answer (score -5):

There are some Python libraries that you cannot install with a simple `conda install` since their channel is not available unless you apply conda-forge. From my experience, pip is more generic to look into different channel sources than conda. 
For instance, if you want to install `python-constraint` you can do it via `pip install` but to install it via **cond **. you have to specify the channel - `conda-forge`.

```
conda install -c conda-forge python-constraint // works
```

but not

```
conda install python-constraint
```

Comment: Confusing answer. pip installing takes the package outside of conda's own package management and dependency verification, which means you need to manage it (and potentially its dependencies) manually and that commands such as `conda update --all` will not update the pip installed package

Comment: This answer gives bad advice.  It is bad practice to interleave conda and pip commands in the same environment.  Use conda install for all packages exclusively, unless a particular python package is not available in conda format.  Then use pip as a last resort, because pip will NOT add the package to the conda package index for that environment.  Using conda, then pip, then conda, then pip, then conda, etc. to build an environment will eventually give a corrupted conda environment index.

Comment: @RichLysakowskiPhD Where did the answer suggested to interleave conda and pip commands in the same environment?
-JeanMonet: The answer is not favoring one over the other. It is about how specifying the channel 'conda-forge' is sometimes helpful.

Comment: The original poster is asking about using conda or conda-forge, so why are you providing an answer about the `pip` package manager?  @Jean Monet also touches upon the pitfall of using pip and conda together, because conda will not update packages which are referenced only in the local pip package index and not in the conda package index.  If you start with conda for environment and package management, then stick with it.  Use pip packages as a last resort and last step when working with conda environments.

Comment: Yes, the original question focused on using conda or conda-forge. And clearly, the answer I provided with example inside the code block targets the question. Here is my understanding, conda, conda-forge, and pip all are Python package managers. So what is the oversight of discussing pip as an option while answering the original question? The answer didn't suggest to use them together. For that matter, using them together is not a sinful act, as long as the user knows how to use them. However, I agree on the downsides described by Jean.