# NetworkX read_shp needs GDAL

Tags: python-3.5, networkx, gdal

I'm on a mac running python3 on jupyter notebook.  Pushing myself to learn more python via a project on road maps.

I'm reading in a shapefile like so

```
import networkx as nx
g = nx.read_shp('Road files/geo_export_4d537b7d-a470-4eb9-b147-1d0ea89e6b60.shp')
```

And it's working dandy.

But then I read about [OSMnx](http://geoffboeing.com/2016/11/osmnx-python-street-networks) and think "that's pretty cool! I could dynamically pull shapefiles, rather than hunt them out online".

So I tried to install (`pip install osmnx`) but kept getting failures.  So I tried the other method mentioned (`conda install -c conda-forge osmnx`).

Now, I can no longer run my initial networkx read_shp because of this error:

```
ImportError: read_shp requires OGR: http://www.gdal.org/
```

.  I've gone to the site and installed GDAL, but the error persists.

I also cannot import osmnx.  It errors on 
`from fiona.ogrext import Iterator, ItemsIterator, KeysIterator` due to

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/sb/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/fiona/ogrext.cpython-35m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libjpeg.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/sb/anaconda/lib/libgdal.20.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

1\ What the heck did I just do to my environment?

2\ How do I restore networkx functionality? Presumably through a proper GDAL (re?)installation.

3\ How do I prep for osmnx?

Sorry for the vague open-endedness here, I've pushed my code a bit too far beyond my abilities.

**Update**
I ran `conda config --add channels conda-forge` and re-running `conda install gdal` and `conda install libgdal`.

Unfortunately I still error out, but it's a different error claiming that networkx needs gdal (which should be installed?)

```
/Users/sb/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/networkx/readwrite/nx_shp.py in read_shp(path, simplify)

ImportError: read_shp requires OGR: http://www.gdal.org/
```

fwiw, `/Users/sb/anaconda/lib/` has both a `python3.6` and `python3.5` folder.

Comment: FWIW, it looks like I'm not alone: https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/issues/25  But following these steps gets me nowhere, and I'm not sure I understand but it seems to be "Anaconda or conda-forge packaging issue"

Answer (score 2):

In general, you might want to avoid mixing [conda channels](https://conda.io/docs/channels.html). Presumably your environment had been defaulting to `defaults` and then you installed OSMnx via the `conda-forge` channel. In practice, it usually works OK but sometimes it can cause package conflicts like what you're seeing.

Per the [OSMnx documentation](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), you could install it in a clean, dedicated virtual environment to ensure it is isolated:

```
conda create --yes -c conda-forge -n OSMNX python=3 osmnx
source activate OSMNX
```

If that still doesn't work then there is indeed an issue with the conda-forge packaging for your platform and version of Python, in which case you should open an issue in its [conda-forge GitHub repo](https://github.com/conda-forge/osmnx-feedstock).

Finally, you might also consider making conda-forge the highest priority channel in your anaconda setup. Check your `.condarc` file and ensure that the `conda-forge` channel is on top of `defaults` so it gets priority. As [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39857289/should-i-use-conda-or-conda-forge-when-creating-anaconda-python-environments) elsewhere suggests, there are 3 main reasons to use the conda-forge channel instead of the defaults channel maintained by Continuum:

1. Packages on conda-forge may be more up-to-date than those on the defaults channel
2. There are packages on the conda-forge channel that aren't available from defaults
3. You would prefer to use a dependency such as openblas (from conda-forge) instead of mkl (from defaults).

Wes McKinney has [similarly commented](http://wesmckinney.com/blog/conda-forge-centos-moment/) on the benefits of using conda-forge.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I don't see a .condarc file in /Users/me, /Users/me/anaconda or /Users/me/anaconda/bin.  Is this something that is created automatically or should I be creating it?

Comment: The conda [documentation](https://conda.io/docs/config.html#the-conda-configuration-file-condarc) discusses the `.condarc` file.

Comment: See also this [conda-forge PR](https://github.com/conda-forge/conda-forge.github.io/pull/325)

Comment: Helpful, turned on conda-forge and did a big install for gdal, then libgdal.  And now the error I get is different: `/Users/sb/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/networkx/readwrite/nx_shp.py in read_shp(path, simplify)

ImportError: read_shp requires OGR: http://www.gdal.org/
`