# Gensim 4.1.2 installed but not found

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, gensim

I just installed gensim with pip install -u gensim.
Pycharm throws the following error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gensim'

I tried pip3 install gensim, same error (after opening and closing the IDE).
I also installed it with conda install -c anaconda gensim.
Gensim 4.1.2 shows up both in my pip list and my conda list. Both gensim and numpy are up to date, so I'm not sure what's going wrong, any ideas?

edit:
I'm using Windows 10, Numpy 1.21.2 (and Gensim 4.1.2)

Comment: Check this discussion (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46168600/gensim-error-no-module-named-gensim), I think there you can find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

the venv file of Pycharm and anaconda may not be the same, you can set it from the Interpreter section of the settings, I'm happy if I could help

Comment: My interpreter is currently set to the default Python3.8 interpreter. It is my understanding that this should work if I use pip install?

Comment: You should use anaconda python interpreter, see https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/integration/python-path/