# Pip install error for GDAL 2.2.4 on windows

Tags: python, pip, conda, gdal

I am trying to install/upgrade GDAL 2.2.4. But every time i try to install or upgrade to version GDAL 2.2.4 i get an error message. I have completely uninstalled and reinstalled anaconda (64bit) (with python 2.7). 
Using the `conda` command to install in command line (i.e. `conda install gdal)` works fine. However, it only installs to GDAL 2.2.2. I need the newest version for its capacity to handle BigTIFF formats. When I use pip to install (i.e. `pip install gdal`) I get this massive error [i took a screen shot because i dont know how to copy from cmd]:

**How do I overcome this error and install GDAL 2.2.4 ?**

Comment: btw, i tried installing gdal 2.2.4 on my mac...same issue, different error.

Comment: Please do not post terminal output in images. See here for why: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086

Comment: copy that! Thanks. COuld you let me know how i copy text from terminal?

Comment: On Windows? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11543578/copy-text-from-a-windows-cmd-window-to-clipboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gdal 2.2.4 is available through anaconda with conda-forge.

Try the following

```
conda install -c conda-forge gdal
```

Comment: thanks! This worked. Although I am still confused about the error message...nice work around though.

Comment: btw...what is conda-forge?

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39857289/should-conda-or-conda-forge-be-used-for-python-environments) explains it quite well. In general it is just another channel, meaning that the packages on the default channels and conda-forge are not build by the same persons/processes. In my personal experience, conda-forge is often more up to date, and at least for me the binaries works way more often.