# Scrapy Installation Error: [CondaEnvironmentNotFoundError] : could not find environment: base

Tags: scrapy, conda

I'm currently trying to install scrapy when I encountered my first error:

> ERROR conda.core.link:_execute_actions(337): An error occurred while installing package 'conda-forge::automat-0.7.0-py_1'.
>   CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. D:\ProgramFiles\Python\Scripts\conda.exe
>   Running `conda clean --packages` may resolve your problem.
>   Attempting to roll back.
>
> CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. D:\ProgramFiles\Python\Scripts\conda.exe
>   Running `conda clean --packages` may resolve your problem.

I researched this error and followed the advice on [this link](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7713):

My issues were largely similar to his until I reached the comment which advised me to run `conda update -n base conda`.

When I ran this code, I encountered my next error:

> CondaEnvironmentNotFoundError: Could not find environment: base .
>   You can list all discoverable environments with `conda info --envs`.

Kindly advice if my steps taken were appropriate and how can I fix this issue.

The weird thing is I installed scrapy before, and these errors occurred after I recently re-installed Anaconda.

I'm not sure what other info you might require to better understand the situation. Do let me know and I will assist promptly.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Try the `conda install scrapy` channel instead of the `conda-forge` channel.
To understand the difference between these two channels please read the answer of the following question [Should conda, or conda-forge be used for Python environments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39857289/should-conda-or-conda-forge-be-used-for-python-environments)