# Updating a Conda environment only through conda-forge channel

Tags: conda, miniconda

I have Miniconda installed with 2 environments:  **base** and *gis*. Packages in **gis** were installed from *coda-forge*. I have 2 questions:

Q1)   want to update all packages in **gis** environment only from *conda-forge*. Am I using correct command ?

Q2) Why it is downgrading numpy-base ?  It is updating other packages and when  *conda-forge* still has several newer versions of 1.15.3 of numpy-base, why it is being downgraded ?

> (gis) [arnuld@arch64 ~]$ conda update --all -c conda-forge
>   Solving environment: done
>
> ### Package Plan
>
> environment location: /home/arnuld/.local/miniconda/envs/gis
>
> The following packages will be downloaded:
>
> ```
> package                    |            build
> ---------------------------|-----------------
> matplotlib-3.0.1           |       h8a2030e_1           6 KB  conda-forge
> openblas-0.3.3             |       ha44fe06_1        13.7 MB  conda-forge
> libopenblas-0.2.20         |       h9ac9557_7         8.8 MB
> numpy-base-1.14.3          |   py36h0ea5e3f_1         4.1 MB
> blas-1.1                   |         openblas           1 KB  conda-forge
> krb5-1.16.2                |       hbb41f41_0         1.4 MB  conda-forge
> scipy-1.1.0                |py36_blas_openblashb06ca3d_202        39.8 MB  conda-forge
> mkl_random-1.0.2           |           py36_0         1.3 MB  conda-forge
> numpy-1.15.3               |py36_blas_openblashb06ca3d_0         9.4 MB  conda-forge
> matplotlib-base-3.0.1      |   py36hc039c98_1         9.2 MB  conda-forge
> ------------------------------------------------------------
>                                        Total:        87.6 MB
> ```
>
> The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:
>
> ```
> libopenblas:     0.2.20-h9ac9557_7                
> matplotlib-base: 3.0.1-py36hc039c98_1  conda-forge
> openblas:        0.3.3-ha44fe06_1      conda-forge
> ```
>
> The following packages will be UPDATED:
>
> ```
> blas:            1.0-mkl                           --> 1.1-openblas                         conda-forge
> krb5:            1.16.1-hbb41f41_0     conda-forge --> 1.16.2-hbb41f41_0                    conda-forge
> matplotlib:      2.2.3-py36h8e2386c_0  conda-forge --> 3.0.1-h8a2030e_1                     conda-forge
> mkl_random:      1.0.1-py36_0          conda-forge --> 1.0.2-py36_0                         conda-forge
> numpy:           1.15.0-py36h1b885b7_0             --> 1.15.3-py36_blas_openblashb06ca3d_0  conda-forge [blas_openblas]
> scipy:           1.1.0-py36hc49cb51_0              --> 1.1.0-py36_blas_openblashb06ca3d_202 conda-forge [blas_openblas]
> ```
>
> The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
>
> ```
> numpy-base:      1.15.0-py36h3dfced4_0             --> 1.14.3-py36h0ea5e3f_1
> ```
>
> Proceed ([y]/n)? n

```
[arnuld@arch64 ~]$ conda list -n gis
# packages in environment at /home/arnuld/.local/miniconda/envs/gis:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
attrs                     18.2.0                     py_0    conda-forge
backcall                  0.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
blas                      1.0                         mkl  
bleach                    3.0.2                      py_0    conda-forge
boost-cpp                 1.67.0               h3a22d5f_0    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.6                h470a237_2    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2018.10.15           ha4d7672_0    conda-forge
cairo                     1.14.12              he6fea26_5    conda-forge
certifi                   2018.10.15            py36_1000    conda-forge
click                     7.0                        py_0    conda-forge
click-plugins             1.0.4                      py_0    conda-forge
cligj                     0.5.0                      py_0    conda-forge
curl                      7.62.0               h74213dd_0    conda-forge
cycler                    0.10.0                     py_1    conda-forge
dbus                      1.13.0               h3a4f0e9_0    conda-forge
decorator                 4.3.0                      py_0    conda-forge
descartes                 1.1.0                      py_2    conda-forge
entrypoints               0.2.3                 py36_1002    conda-forge
expat                     2.2.5                hfc679d8_2    conda-forge
fiona                     1.8.0            py36hfc77a4a_0    conda-forge
fontconfig                2.13.1               h65d0f4c_0    conda-forge
freetype                  2.9.1                h6debe1e_4    conda-forge
freexl                    1.0.5                h470a237_2    conda-forge
gdal                      2.3.2            py36hb00a9d7_0    conda-forge
geopandas                 0.4.0                      py_1    conda-forge
geos                      3.6.2                hfc679d8_3    conda-forge
geotiff                   1.4.2                h700e5ad_5    conda-forge
gettext                   0.19.8.1             h5e8e0c9_1    conda-forge
giflib                    5.1.4                h470a237_1    conda-forge
glib                      2.55.0               h464dc38_2    conda-forge
gmp                       6.1.2                hfc679d8_0    conda-forge
gst-plugins-base          1.12.5               hde13a9d_0    conda-forge
gstreamer                 1.12.5               h61a6719_0    conda-forge
hdf4                      4.2.13               h951d187_2    conda-forge
hdf5                      1.10.3               hc401514_2    conda-forge
icu                       58.2                 hfc679d8_0    conda-forge
intel-openmp              2019.0                      118  
ipykernel                 5.1.0              pyh24bf2e0_0    conda-forge
ipython                   7.1.1           py36h24bf2e0_1000    conda-forge
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                      py_1    conda-forge
jedi                      0.13.1                py36_1000    conda-forge
jinja2                    2.10                       py_1    conda-forge
jpeg                      9c                   h470a237_1    conda-forge
json-c                    0.12.1               h470a237_1    conda-forge
jsonschema                3.0.0a3               py36_1000    conda-forge
jupyter_client            5.2.3                      py_1    conda-forge
jupyter_core              4.4.0                      py_0    conda-forge
kealib                    1.4.10               hb88cf67_0    conda-forge
kiwisolver                1.0.1            py36h2d50403_2    conda-forge
krb5                      1.16.1               hbb41f41_0    conda-forge
libcurl                   7.62.0               hbdb9355_0    conda-forge
libdap4                   3.19.1               h8fe5423_1    conda-forge
libedit                   3.1.20170329         haf1bffa_1    conda-forge
libffi                    3.2.1                hfc679d8_5    conda-forge
libgcc-ng                 7.2.0                hdf63c60_3    conda-forge
libgdal                   2.3.2                hc73897a_0    conda-forge
libgfortran               3.0.0                         1    conda-forge
libgfortran-ng            7.2.0                hdf63c60_3    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.15                 h470a237_3    conda-forge
libkml                    1.3.0                hccc92b1_8    conda-forge
libnetcdf                 4.6.1               h9cd6fdc_11    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.35               ha92aebf_2    conda-forge
libpq                     10.5                 he29860b_0    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.16               h470a237_1    conda-forge
libspatialindex           1.8.5                hfc679d8_3    conda-forge
libspatialite             4.3.0a              hdfcc80b_23    conda-forge
libssh2                   1.8.0                h5b517e9_2    conda-forge
libstdcxx-ng              7.2.0                hdf63c60_3    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.0.9                he6b73bb_2    conda-forge
libuuid                   2.32.1               h470a237_2    conda-forge
libxcb                    1.13                 h470a237_2    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.9.8                h422b904_5    conda-forge
markupsafe                1.0              py36h470a237_1    conda-forge
matplotlib                2.2.3            py36h8e2386c_0    conda-forge
mistune                   0.8.4            py36h470a237_0    conda-forge
mkl                       2019.0                      118  
mkl_fft                   1.0.6                    py36_0    conda-forge
mkl_random                1.0.1                    py36_0    conda-forge
munch                     2.3.2                      py_0    conda-forge
nbconvert                 5.3.1                      py_1    conda-forge
nbformat                  4.4.0                      py_1    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.1                  hfc679d8_1    conda-forge
notebook                  5.7.0                 py36_1000    conda-forge
numpy                     1.15.0           py36h1b885b7_0  
numpy-base                1.15.0           py36h3dfced4_0  
openjpeg                  2.3.0                h0e734dc_3    conda-forge
openssl                   1.0.2p               h470a237_1    conda-forge
pandas                    0.23.4           py36hf8a1672_0    conda-forge
pandoc                    2.3.1                         0    conda-forge
pandocfilters             1.4.2                      py_1    conda-forge
parso                     0.3.1                      py_0    conda-forge
pcre                      8.41                 hfc679d8_3    conda-forge
pexpect                   4.6.0                 py36_1000    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5                 py36_1000    conda-forge
pip                       18.1                  py36_1000    conda-forge
pixman                    0.34.0               h470a237_3    conda-forge
poppler                   0.67.0               h4d7e492_3    conda-forge
poppler-data              0.4.9                         0    conda-forge
postgresql                10.5                 h66035e0_0    conda-forge
proj4                     4.9.3                h470a237_8    conda-forge
prometheus_client         0.4.2                      py_0    conda-forge
prompt_toolkit            2.0.7                      py_0    conda-forge
psycopg2                  2.7.5            py36hdffb7b8_2    conda-forge
pthread-stubs             0.4                  h470a237_1    conda-forge
ptyprocess                0.6.0                 py36_1000    conda-forge
pygments                  2.2.0                      py_1    conda-forge
pyparsing                 2.3.0                      py_0    conda-forge
pyproj                    1.9.5.1          py36h508ed2a_6    conda-forge
pyqt                      5.6.0            py36h8210e8a_7    conda-forge
pyrsistent                0.14.5           py36h470a237_1    conda-forge
pysal                     1.14.4.post2          py36_1001    conda-forge
python                    3.6.6                h5001a0f_3    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.7.5                      py_0    conda-forge
pytz                      2018.7                     py_0    conda-forge
pyzmq                     17.1.2           py36hae99301_1    conda-forge
qt                        5.6.2                hf70d934_9    conda-forge
readline                  7.0                  haf1bffa_1    conda-forge
rtree                     0.8.3                 py36_1000    conda-forge
scipy                     1.1.0            py36hc49cb51_0  
send2trash                1.5.0                      py_0    conda-forge
setuptools                40.5.0                   py36_0    conda-forge
shapely                   1.6.4            py36h164cb2d_1    conda-forge
sip                       4.18.1           py36hfc679d8_0    conda-forge
six                       1.11.0                py36_1001    conda-forge
sqlalchemy                1.2.13           py36h470a237_0    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.25.2               hb1c47c0_0    conda-forge
terminado                 0.8.1                 py36_1001    conda-forge
testpath                  0.4.2                 py36_1000    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.8                ha92aebf_0    conda-forge
tornado                   5.1.1            py36h470a237_0    conda-forge
traitlets                 4.3.2                 py36_1000    conda-forge
wcwidth                   0.1.7                      py_1    conda-forge
webencodings              0.5.1                      py_1    conda-forge
wheel                     0.32.2                   py36_0    conda-forge
xerces-c                  3.2.0                h5d6a6da_2    conda-forge
xorg-kbproto              1.0.7                h470a237_2    conda-forge
xorg-libice               1.0.9                h470a237_4    conda-forge
xorg-libsm                1.2.3                h8c8a85c_0    conda-forge
xorg-libx11               1.6.6                h470a237_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxau               1.0.8                h470a237_6    conda-forge
xorg-libxdmcp             1.1.2                h470a237_7    conda-forge
xorg-libxext              1.3.3                h470a237_4    conda-forge
xorg-libxrender           0.9.10               h470a237_2    conda-forge
xorg-renderproto          0.11.1               h470a237_2    conda-forge
xorg-xextproto            7.3.0                h470a237_2    conda-forge
xorg-xproto               7.0.31               h470a237_7    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.4                h470a237_1    conda-forge
zeromq                    4.2.5                hfc679d8_6    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.11               h470a237_3    conda-forge
[arnuld@arch64 ~]$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Q1

Yes, that's the right command.  However, some of your packages aren't in `conda-forge`, e.g., `numpy-base`:

```
conda search conda-forge::numpy-base
```

turns up empty, same for `libopenblas`.  They are falling back to updating from the `defaults` channel.

### Q2

Don't know for sure, but it seems your BLAS libraries are involved too. Namely, `libopenblas` also has 0.3.3 version available in `defaults`, whereas here it shows installing 0.2.2.  This happens to be a dependency of `numpy-base`, and specifically version 1.15.3 requires `libopenblas>=0.3.3`.

Could have something to do with the `mkl` to `openblas` switch that happens when prioritizing `conda-forge`.  I think we'd need to know the other libraries installed (not being changed during update) to precisely answer this question as posed.

It looks like [this script for searching the conda dependency graph](https://github.com/rvalieris/conda-tree) could be useful for further inspection if you're really interested in assigning the blame.

Comment: I updated the post with list of installed packages. My question is if I want to keep the environments/packages up to date then what should I do ?   One solution I got on the [official forum] (https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/conda/ckxy8TvRfsY)  is to remove the _defaults_ channel:

Comment: By the way, conda-forge does have **numpy**, it is just called numpy . May be it is not distributed as 2 packages,  numpy and  numpy-base, the way _defaults_ channels does:  https://github.com/conda-forge/numpy-feedstock

Comment: this could be the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39862730/9814557

Answer (score 2):

This issue of incompatibility of *defaults* and *conda-forge* channel is pretty much everywhere I see:

https://github.com/conda-forge/numpy-feedstock/issues/108
https://github.com/conda-forge/conda-forge.github.io/issues/232

Since almost all packages which are in *defaults* channel are already in *conda-forge* and "mkl" library  from *defaults* is not Open-Source but its replacement "blas" is, I decided to get rid of *defaults* and replace it with *conda-forge*. So What I did is this:

- remove Miniconda installation (miniconda directory and config files etc)
- installed it again
- conda config --add channels conda-forge
- conda install conda
- conda update --all

This changed the config file:

```
[arnuld@arch64 ~]$ cat .condarc 
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
[arnuld@arch64 ~]$
```

That means *conda-forge* got priority over *defaults* and all packages will be searched first in *conda-forge* and if not found there, only then in *defaults*. Works for me:

```
    [arnuld@arch64 ~]$ conda install conda
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /mnt/sda5/.miniconda3

  added / updated specs: 
    - conda


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    conda-4.5.11               |        py37_1000         651 KB  conda-forge
    ca-certificates-2018.10.15 |       ha4d7672_0         135 KB  conda-forge
    openssl-1.0.2p             |       h470a237_1         3.1 MB  conda-forge
    certifi-2018.10.15         |        py37_1000         138 KB  conda-forge
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:         4.0 MB

The following packages will be UPDATED:

    ca-certificates: 2018.03.07-0      --> 2018.10.15-ha4d7672_0 conda-forge
    certifi:         2018.8.24-py37_1  --> 2018.10.15-py37_1000  conda-forge
    conda:           4.5.11-py37_0     --> 4.5.11-py37_1000      conda-forge
    openssl:         1.0.2p-h14c3975_0 --> 1.0.2p-h470a237_1     conda-forge

Proceed ([y]/n)? y
```

---

```
[arnuld@arch64 ~]$ conda update --all
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /mnt/sda5/.miniconda3


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    pysocks-1.6.8              |        py37_1002          22 KB  conda-forge
    six-1.11.0                 |        py37_1001          21 KB  conda-forge
    ncurses-6.1                |       hfc679d8_1         1.2 MB  conda-forge
    pycosat-0.6.3              |   py37h470a237_1         103 KB  conda-forge
    cryptography-2.3.1         |   py37hdffb7b8_0         587 KB  conda-forge
    libstdcxx-ng-7.2.0         |       hdf63c60_3         2.5 MB  conda-forge
    ruamel_yaml-0.15.71        |   py37h470a237_0         265 KB  conda-forge
    xz-5.2.4                   |       h470a237_1         328 KB  conda-forge
    cffi-1.11.5                |   py37h5e8e0c9_1         406 KB  conda-forge
    pyopenssl-18.0.0           |        py37_1000          81 KB  conda-forge
    libffi-3.2.1               |       hfc679d8_5          51 KB  conda-forge
    bzip2-1.0.6                |       h470a237_2         310 KB  conda-forge
    sqlite-3.25.2              |       hb1c47c0_0         1.6 MB  conda-forge
    urllib3-1.23               |        py37_1001         151 KB  conda-forge
    yaml-0.1.7                 |       h470a237_1          77 KB  conda-forge
    asn1crypto-0.24.0          |        py37_1003         154 KB  conda-forge
    libedit-3.1.20170329       |       haf1bffa_1         158 KB  conda-forge
    libgcc-ng-7.2.0            |       hdf63c60_3         6.1 MB  conda-forge
    zlib-1.2.11                |       h470a237_3          93 KB  conda-forge
    python-3.7.0               |       h5001a0f_4        25.2 MB  conda-forge
    pycparser-2.19             |             py_0          87 KB  conda-forge
    wheel-0.32.2               |           py37_0          34 KB  conda-forge
    chardet-3.0.4              |        py37_1003         167 KB  conda-forge
    conda-env-2.6.0            |                1           2 KB  conda-forge
    setuptools-40.5.0          |           py37_0         619 KB  conda-forge
    idna-2.7                   |        py37_1002          99 KB  conda-forge
    pip-18.1                   |        py37_1000         1.7 MB  conda-forge
    readline-7.0               |       haf1bffa_1         381 KB  conda-forge
    requests-2.20.0            |        py37_1000          83 KB  conda-forge
    tk-8.6.8                   |       ha92aebf_0         3.1 MB  conda-forge
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        45.6 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    bzip2:        1.0.6-h470a237_2        conda-forge

The following packages will be UPDATED:

    asn1crypto:   0.24.0-py37_0                       --> 0.24.0-py37_1003        conda-forge
    cffi:         1.11.5-py37he75722e_1               --> 1.11.5-py37h5e8e0c9_1   conda-forge
    chardet:      3.0.4-py37_1                        --> 3.0.4-py37_1003         conda-forge
    conda-env:    2.6.0-1                             --> 2.6.0-1                 conda-forge
    cryptography: 2.3.1-py37hc365091_0                --> 2.3.1-py37hdffb7b8_0    conda-forge
    idna:         2.7-py37_0                          --> 2.7-py37_1002           conda-forge
    libffi:       3.2.1-hd88cf55_4                    --> 3.2.1-hfc679d8_5        conda-forge
    ncurses:      6.1-hf484d3e_0                      --> 6.1-hfc679d8_1          conda-forge
    pip:          10.0.1-py37_0                       --> 18.1-py37_1000          conda-forge
    pycosat:      0.6.3-py37h14c3975_0                --> 0.6.3-py37h470a237_1    conda-forge
    pycparser:    2.18-py37_1                         --> 2.19-py_0               conda-forge
    pyopenssl:    18.0.0-py37_0                       --> 18.0.0-py37_1000        conda-forge
    pysocks:      1.6.8-py37_0                        --> 1.6.8-py37_1002         conda-forge
    python:       3.7.0-hc3d631a_0                    --> 3.7.0-h5001a0f_4        conda-forge
    requests:     2.19.1-py37_0                       --> 2.20.0-py37_1000        conda-forge
    ruamel_yaml:  0.15.46-py37h14c3975_0              --> 0.15.71-py37h470a237_0  conda-forge
    setuptools:   40.2.0-py37_0                       --> 40.5.0-py37_0           conda-forge
    six:          1.11.0-py37_1                       --> 1.11.0-py37_1001        conda-forge
    sqlite:       3.24.0-h84994c4_0                   --> 3.25.2-hb1c47c0_0       conda-forge
    tk:           8.6.8-hbc83047_0                    --> 8.6.8-ha92aebf_0        conda-forge
    urllib3:      1.23-py37_0                         --> 1.23-py37_1001          conda-forge
    wheel:        0.31.1-py37_0                       --> 0.32.2-py37_0           conda-forge
    zlib:         1.2.11-ha838bed_2                   --> 1.2.11-h470a237_3       conda-forge

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

    libedit:      3.1.20170329-h6b74fdf_2             --> 3.1.20170329-haf1bffa_1 conda-forge
    libgcc-ng:    8.2.0-hdf63c60_1                    --> 7.2.0-hdf63c60_3        conda-forge
    libstdcxx-ng: 8.2.0-hdf63c60_1                    --> 7.2.0-hdf63c60_3        conda-forge
    readline:     7.0-h7b6447c_5                      --> 7.0-haf1bffa_1          conda-forge
    xz:           5.2.4-h14c3975_4                    --> 5.2.4-h470a237_1        conda-forge
    yaml:         0.1.7-had09818_2                    --> 0.1.7-h470a237_1        conda-forge

Proceed ([y]/n)? y
```

Now all packages are always installed from *conda-forge*:

```
[arnuld@arch64 ~]$ conda install scipy pandas notebook ipython
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /mnt/sda5/.miniconda3

  added / updated specs: 
    - ipython
    - notebook
    - pandas
    - scipy


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    pygments-2.2.0             |             py_1         622 KB  conda-forge
    jupyter_client-5.2.3       |             py_1          59 KB  conda-forge
    pexpect-4.6.0              |        py37_1000          75 KB  conda-forge
    markupsafe-1.0             |   py37h470a237_1          33 KB  conda-forge
    prompt_toolkit-2.0.7       |             py_0         218 KB  conda-forge
    openblas-0.3.3             |       ha44fe06_1        13.7 MB  conda-forge
    ptyprocess-0.6.0           |        py37_1000          22 KB  conda-forge
    testpath-0.4.2             |        py37_1000          91 KB  conda-forge
    entrypoints-0.2.3          |        py37_1002           9 KB  conda-forge
    blas-1.1                   |         openblas           1 KB  conda-forge
    pandoc-2.3.1               |                0        20.7 MB  conda-forge
    pyrsistent-0.14.5          |   py37h470a237_1          85 KB  conda-forge
    ipython-7.1.1              |py37h24bf2e0_1000         1.1 MB  conda-forge
    wcwidth-0.1.7              |             py_1          17 KB  conda-forge
    webencodings-0.5.1         |             py_1          12 KB  conda-forge
    send2trash-1.5.0           |             py_0          12 KB  conda-forge
    numpy-1.15.4               |py37_blas_openblashb06ca3d_0         4.2 MB  conda-forge
    pandas-0.23.4              |   py37hf8a1672_0        27.5 MB  conda-forge
    gmp-6.1.2                  |       hfc679d8_0         676 KB  conda-forge
    pytz-2018.7                |             py_0         226 KB  conda-forge
    mistune-0.8.4              |   py37h470a237_0          53 KB  conda-forge
    parso-0.3.1                |             py_0          59 KB  conda-forge
    jedi-0.13.1                |        py37_1000         228 KB  conda-forge
    python-dateutil-2.7.5      |             py_0         218 KB  conda-forge
    zeromq-4.2.5               |       hfc679d8_6         939 KB  conda-forge
    decorator-4.3.0            |             py_0          10 KB  conda-forge
    jupyter_core-4.4.0         |             py_0          44 KB  conda-forge
    attrs-18.2.0               |             py_0          30 KB  conda-forge
    pickleshare-0.7.5          |        py37_1000          12 KB  conda-forge
    nbconvert-5.3.1            |             py_1         320 KB  conda-forge
    pandocfilters-1.4.2        |             py_1           9 KB  conda-forge
    traitlets-4.3.2            |        py37_1000         130 KB  conda-forge
    bleach-3.0.2               |             py_0         125 KB  conda-forge
    ipykernel-5.1.0            |     pyh24bf2e0_0          77 KB  conda-forge
    jsonschema-3.0.0a3         |        py37_1000          80 KB  conda-forge
    prometheus_client-0.4.2    |             py_0          32 KB  conda-forge
    tornado-5.1.1              |   py37h470a237_0         662 KB  conda-forge
    terminado-0.8.1            |        py37_1001          23 KB  conda-forge
    libgfortran-3.0.0          |                1         281 KB  conda-forge
    nbformat-4.4.0             |             py_1          91 KB  conda-forge
    jinja2-2.10                |             py_1          89 KB  conda-forge
    notebook-5.7.0             |        py37_1000         7.3 MB  conda-forge
    backcall-0.1.0             |             py_0          13 KB  conda-forge
    pyzmq-17.1.2               |   py37hae99301_1         455 KB  conda-forge
    ipython_genutils-0.2.0     |             py_1          21 KB  conda-forge
    scipy-1.1.0                |py37_blas_openblashb06ca3d_202        17.5 MB  conda-forge
    libsodium-1.0.16           |       h470a237_1         536 KB  conda-forge
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        98.5 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    attrs:             18.2.0-py_0                          conda-forge
    backcall:          0.1.0-py_0                           conda-forge
    blas:              1.1-openblas                         conda-forge
    bleach:            3.0.2-py_0                           conda-forge
    decorator:         4.3.0-py_0                           conda-forge
    entrypoints:       0.2.3-py37_1002                      conda-forge
    gmp:               6.1.2-hfc679d8_0                     conda-forge
    ipykernel:         5.1.0-pyh24bf2e0_0                   conda-forge
    ipython:           7.1.1-py37h24bf2e0_1000              conda-forge
    ipython_genutils:  0.2.0-py_1                           conda-forge
    jedi:              0.13.1-py37_1000                     conda-forge
    jinja2:            2.10-py_1                            conda-forge
    jsonschema:        3.0.0a3-py37_1000                    conda-forge
    jupyter_client:    5.2.3-py_1                           conda-forge
    jupyter_core:      4.4.0-py_0                           conda-forge
    libgfortran:       3.0.0-1                              conda-forge
    libsodium:         1.0.16-h470a237_1                    conda-forge
    markupsafe:        1.0-py37h470a237_1                   conda-forge
    mistune:           0.8.4-py37h470a237_0                 conda-forge
    nbconvert:         5.3.1-py_1                           conda-forge
    nbformat:          4.4.0-py_1                           conda-forge
    notebook:          5.7.0-py37_1000                      conda-forge
    numpy:             1.15.4-py37_blas_openblashb06ca3d_0  conda-forge [blas_openblas]
    openblas:          0.3.3-ha44fe06_1                     conda-forge
    pandas:            0.23.4-py37hf8a1672_0                conda-forge
    pandoc:            2.3.1-0                              conda-forge
    pandocfilters:     1.4.2-py_1                           conda-forge
    parso:             0.3.1-py_0                           conda-forge
    pexpect:           4.6.0-py37_1000                      conda-forge
    pickleshare:       0.7.5-py37_1000                      conda-forge
    prometheus_client: 0.4.2-py_0                           conda-forge
    prompt_toolkit:    2.0.7-py_0                           conda-forge
    ptyprocess:        0.6.0-py37_1000                      conda-forge
    pygments:          2.2.0-py_1                           conda-forge
    pyrsistent:        0.14.5-py37h470a237_1                conda-forge
    python-dateutil:   2.7.5-py_0                           conda-forge
    pytz:              2018.7-py_0                          conda-forge
    pyzmq:             17.1.2-py37hae99301_1                conda-forge
    scipy:             1.1.0-py37_blas_openblashb06ca3d_202 conda-forge [blas_openblas]
    send2trash:        1.5.0-py_0                           conda-forge
    terminado:         0.8.1-py37_1001                      conda-forge
    testpath:          0.4.2-py37_1000                      conda-forge
    tornado:           5.1.1-py37h470a237_0                 conda-forge
    traitlets:         4.3.2-py37_1000                      conda-forge
    wcwidth:           0.1.7-py_1                           conda-forge
    webencodings:      0.5.1-py_1                           conda-forge
    zeromq:            4.2.5-hfc679d8_6                     conda-forge

Proceed ([y]/n)? y
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I just don't see the motivation. Unless there is some specific version/method/bug fix you require in the bleeding-edge releases, it doesn't seem justified. And if you do have specific requirements, that's what pinning functions are for. Personally, I'd never give conda-forge higher priority over defaults simply because MKL is faster than OpenBLAS on Intel hardware.

Comment: Hey Merv, I am really thanksful for your help. I am fine with conda-forge. I kinda like community-driven Open-Source stuff.  

I use Arch Linux (pretty much of bleeding-edge) and I use AMD Phenom Processor. So, MKL does not make much difference to me. 2nd,  I use Open-Source software mostly and want to put projects on GitHub and I don't want to anyone using my software to get stuck into proprietary licensing problems. Even if I use _defaults_ channel, I will still remove MKL. Then 3rd,  _conda-forge_ has everything that _defaults_ has + lot more.

Comment: Five years out from my previous comment, I’ve definitely changed my opinion: I never use `defaults` (`anaconda`) channel. I’ve since learned to precisely control BLAS with `conda install 'blas=*=mkl'` or whatever my hardware-specific preference is (e.g., `accelerate` on Apple Silicon). I even go as far as including the pseudo-channel `nodefaults` in YAML environment definitions to explicitly ban other channels.