# How to understand conda package channel

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

An extension of the question [Should conda, or conda-forge be used for Python environments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39857289/should-conda-or-conda-forge-be-used-for-python-environments) , is there an online explanation of conda packages, or a way for the layman to know what package is the right one to install?

For example, searching for conda install opencv, there is the [conda-forge link](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/opencv) that has 480k downloads and [anaconda link](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/opencv) that has 42k downloads.  Then other stackoverflow questions [How do I install Python OpenCV through Conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23119413/how-do-i-install-python-opencv-through-conda/45603276) get answers for [menpo link](https://anaconda.org/menpo/opencv) with 150k downloads.

Are all the channels 'safe' in that they are vetted and not random people? Is there a comparison site showing the differences between the options?

Comment: I am not an employee of Anaconda, Inc. However, my understanding is that, like most open-source software repositories, the reputation of the "channel" is all you can go by. The channels are not vetted (unless the owner specifies how they vet the code). As far as I know, there is no comparison site, but that question is not on-topic for SO anyways...