# how to specify conda package dependence and its channel

Tags: conda, packaging

I am learning how to create conda packages and I would like to understand how to specify a dependence with a specific channel

The reason I've chosen conda is that my package has a dependency that doesn't get smoothly installed from pypi. My dependency package (`pycocoapi`) on PyPi has its own un-specified dependency (`Cython`)-- thus one has to do manual preinstallation, and I need it to work out of box.

Therefore, I want to use this conda [`pycocotools` package](https://anaconda.org/HCC/pycocotools): `conda install -c hcc pycocotools`

How can I specify this dependency and its channel in a conda recipe?

Answer (score 1):

`conda config --append channels some-channel`

For more details see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39862730/8313807).