# cvxopt.solvers.qp in python causes the kernel to die

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, cvxopt

When I try to solve a quadratic programming problem with solvers.qp from the cvxopt package in python, it kills my kernel after a few seconds.

The documentation of the package is found at http://cvxopt.org/userguide/coneprog.html#cvxopt.solvers.qp . If I run the example code from that page:

```
from math import sqrt
from cvxopt import matrix
from cvxopt.solvers import qp

# Problem data.
n = 4
S = matrix([[ 4e-2,  6e-3, -4e-3,    0.0 ],
        [ 6e-3,  1e-2,  0.0,     0.0 ],
        [-4e-3,  0.0,   2.5e-3,  0.0 ],
        [ 0.0,   0.0,   0.0,     0.0 ]])
pbar = matrix([.12, .10, .07, .03])
G = matrix(0.0, (n,n))
G[::n+1] = -1.0 
h = matrix(0.0, (n,1))
A = matrix(1.0, (1,n))
b = matrix(1.0)

# Compute trade-off.
N = 100
mus = [ 10**(5.0*t/N-1.0) for t in range(N) ]

portfolios = [ qp(mu*S, -pbar, G, h, A, b)['x'] for mu in mus ]
```

After 2 seconds or so I get the following reply from python:

> It seems the kernel died unexpectedly. Use 'Restart kernel' to continue using this console.
>
> It seems the kernel died unexpectedly. Use 'Restart kernel' to continue using this console.
>
> It seems the kernel died unexpectedly. Use 'Restart kernel' to continue using this console.
>
> ...

I also don't understand what this ['x'] option is all about. But even if I leave that away it gives me that 'unexpected' death of the kernel. I also tried qp problems that definitely have a solution. Like x^2+y^2 under no constraints or with non-negativity constraints... what ever I do, it kills my kernel. What could be the problem?

Maybe it is important to say, that

- I use Ubuntu 16
- I use Python 3.5
- I use cvxopt 1.1.9
- The package cvxopt also uses C-files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem, when I was running cvxopt in Jupyter Lab, so I moved my code to PyCharm and got an error

> OMP: Error #15: Initializing libiomp5md.dll, but found libiomp5md.dll already initialized.

> OMP: Hint This means that multiple copies of the OpenMP runtime have been linked into the program. That is dangerous, since it can degrade performance or cause incorrect results.

I googled and found [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20554074/sklearn-omp-error-15-initializing-libiomp5md-dll-but-found-mk2iomp5md-dll-a) that solved it via

```
    import os
    os.environ["KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK"]="TRUE"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run the script from terminal to get cause of this error.

When I got this error, the cause is `Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load libmkl_avx2.so or libmkl_def.so`.
I use conda so that's my solution:

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda install -f cvxopt
```