# How to fix 'The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically" caused by pytorch

Tags: jupyter, pytorch

I have a strange problem with Pytorch. When I use torch functions with tensors like `tensor.reshape`  or `torch.transpose`, I don't have any problems; even when I created networks, it's ok. However, when I want to train network my jupyter crashed.

[image: crashed]

I find where error is but I don't know why it is there and how to fix it.

[image: errors]

I installed pytorch using conda. I have Ubuntu 18.04.
I don't have cuda.

Comment: In "error" don't see preds=x_batch. It's never mind.

Comment: Batch size? You may run out of RAM memory or GPU memory, try to lower it down.

Comment: tried reduce batch size - Doesn't work. In keras this example work.

Answer (score 4):

The hint for the solution is available, via the Jupyter notebook terminal (if opened it directly and not via the anaconda interface), where a more proper error code appears

> OMP: Error #15: Initializing libiomp5md.dll, but found libiomp5md.dll
> already initialized. OMP: Hint This means that multiple copies of the
> OpenMP runtime have been linked into the program....

which then leads to a working solution here
[sklearn OMP: Error #15 when fitting models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20554074/sklearn-omp-error-15-when-fitting-models#29533344)

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Ubuntu you may not install PyTorch just via conda.

It can be:

- Conda
- Pip
- LibTorch
- From Source

So you have multiple options.

Go to this [page](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) and select Cuda to NONE, LINUX, stable 1.1, CONDA.

```
conda install pytorch-cpu torchvision-cpu -c pytorch
```

If you have problems still, you may try also install PIP way.

```
pip3 install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.1.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
pip3 install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torchvision-0.3.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Hopefully some of these ways will work.

Comment: I don't know how to fix it, but in GoogleColab i can work and my code is work

Comment: in my case problem resolved when i reinstalled Pytorch and cudatoolkit via pip command instead of conda.

Answer (score 1):

Simple Solution

I have solved this problem by reinstalling the torchvision, as this was the only library that was creating an issue, whenever i import that

Just reinstall that:

Directly in Jupyter notebook:

```
!pip3 uninstall -y torch torchvision
!pip3 install torch torchvision
```

or in Terminal:

```
pip3 uninstall -y torch torchvision
pip3 install torch torchvision
```

Answer (score 0):

I had sort of the same issue (on a macos 12.6.2). A kernel crash when using torchvision.

```
trainset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True,
                                        download=True, transform=transform)   
testset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=False,
                                       download=True, transform=transform)

classes = ('plane', 'car', 'bird', 'cat',
           'deer', 'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck')

batch_size = 64
trainloader = th.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=batch_size,
                                          shuffle=True, num_workers=0)
testloader = th.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=batch_size,
                                         shuffle=False, num_workers=0)
dataiter = iter(trainloader)
images, labels = next(dataiter)
```

I solved it by reinstalling pytorch and torchvision. Run in a script (jupyter notebook or elsewhere):

```
!conda install --yes pytorch torchvision -c pytorch
```