# Error #15: Initializing libiomp5md.dll, but found libiomp5md.dll already initialized

Tags: python

Operating System: Window10

I use spyder (python3.8) in anaconda and after run the code, I get the following error:

> [SpyderKernelApp] WARNING | No such comm: df7601e106dd11eba18accf9e4a3c0ef
>
> OMP: Error #15: Initializing libiomp5md.dll, but found libiomp5md.dll already initialized.
>
> OMP: Hint This means that multiple copies of the OpenMP runtime have been linked into the program. That is dangerous, since it can degrade performance or cause incorrect results. The best thing to do is to ensure that only a single OpenMP runtime is linked into the process, e.g. by avoiding static linking of the OpenMP runtime in any library. As an unsafe, unsupported, undocumented workaround you can set the environment variable `KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK=TRUE` to allow the program to continue to execute, but that may cause crashes or silently produce incorrect results. For more information, please see http://www.intel.com/software/products/support/.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Not sure if it will help you, but in my case, (I had exactly the same error) the culprit was a module, more specifically the `import` statement. I moved it a few lines lower and the error went away. Apparently it matters which functions have already been imported.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sklearn OMP: Error #15 ("Initializing libiomp5md.dll, but found mk2iomp5md.dll already initialized.") when fitting models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20554074/sklearn-omp-error-15-initializing-libiomp5md-dll-but-found-mk2iomp5md-dll-a)

Answer (score 11):

I solved this by upgrading NumPy to version 1.23.4.

```
pip install numpy --upgrade
```

This works fine for me :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Works for me too! You're amazing. Such a simple solution.

Comment: Yep. It solved the error for me. Could you kindly explain a little more? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 9):

```
import os
os.environ['KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK']='True'
```

Answer (score 9):

This error occurs when there are multiple "libiomp5.dll" files within a python interpreter. I fixed it by deleting all of the versions of the file that were not within the module I was using (PyTorch). I would like to point out that this could cause a lot of multiprocessing issues down the road if you don't know what you are doing but I am sure it is nothing that can't be solved by looking it up on StackOverflow.

For more details visit: https://www.programmersought.com/article/53286415201/

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this has been solved and you've moved on, but I just encountered this as well and was able to fix it with reinstalling a package with `pip`.

My machine has an AMD Ryzen 5 3400G CPU, and I frequently do machine learning and deep learning for university research. I first had this problem yesterday when I created a Tensorflow anaconda environment when I already had a separate PyTorch environment. I was also incorporating a colleague's code into mine, so I believe what Aenaon commented is valid, that what is imported matters.

Anyway, my solution - after researching where `mkl` is used - was to repeatedly `pip uninstall` and `pip install` one `mkl`-dependent package at a time until the problem went away when running my program. Somehow it was resolved after doing this the first time for `numpy`. I think it's coincidence, but my desired program works for now without any problems.

Comment: worked for me on window 10 with python 3.6 using Conda env but installing (almost) all packages using pip. Uninstalling/installing numpy/scipy/matplotlib using pip did the trick for me.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to fix it by moving import HELPERS late and plus adding the import OS too.

[image]

Comment: Please do not post image of the source code. It is difficult to adopt by someone who wants to try this answer. Post it as a code block.

Answer (score -2):

Had the same problem with

- Anaconda Navigator 2.3.2
- Spyder version: 5.3.3  (conda)
- Python version: 3.9.15 64-bit
- Qt version: 5.15.2
- PyQt5 version: 5.15.7
- Operating System: Windows 10

I detected `libiomp5md.dll` in:

- `..\anaconda3\envs\My_Env\Library\bin`
- `..\anaconda3\pkgs\tensorflow-base-2.9.1-mkl_py39h6a7f48e_1\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python`

I renamed the one in `..\envs\My_Env\Library\bin` to `libiomp5_save.dll`.

and everything was fine.

Don't know if there are any side effects.