# Dead Kernel after running torchvision.utils.make_grid(images)

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, pytorch, torchvision

To make it simple, I am following this [tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html) provided by PyTorch to create a CNN.

However, it appears that when I'm running this particular code block with this respective line:

```
# show images
imshow(torchvision.utils.make_grid(images))
```

It somehow kills the kernel. Which confuses me because it is only a simple function.

I have also went through numerous SO posts that are related to PyTorch but all of them are not related to torchvision. The most similar issue I found was posted 5 months ago without answer.

Please let me know if I need to add on any information to make this question clearer.

Comment: The kernel runs on Python 3 btw

Answer (score 5):

The same thing happened to me. Running these commands in the python interpreter, I got an error that lead me to this:

[Error #15: Initializing libiomp5md.dll, but found libiomp5md.dll already initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64209238/error-15-initializing-libiomp5md-dll-but-found-libiomp5md-dll-already-initial)

when I added the following, it worked:

```
import os
os.environ['KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK']='True'
```

Comment: By the way i checked your post and it does not help my situation, thanks anyway

Comment: It works with me, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had sort of the same issue (on a macos 12.6.2). A kernel crash when using torchvision.

```
trainset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True,
                                        download=True, transform=transform)   
testset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=False,
                                       download=True, transform=transform)

classes = ('plane', 'car', 'bird', 'cat',
           'deer', 'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck')

batch_size = 64
trainloader = th.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=batch_size,
                                          shuffle=True, num_workers=0)
testloader = th.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=batch_size,
                                         shuffle=False, num_workers=0)
dataiter = iter(trainloader)
images, labels = next(dataiter)
```

I solved it by reinstalling pytorch and torchvision. Run in a script (jupyter notebook or elsewhere):

```
!conda install --yes pytorch torchvision -c pytorch
```